# Change http request header without refresh in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies

I'm writing a website which uses ngRoute for changing pages.
for logging in a form will appear and when it's successful controller changes the http header for requests in the next steps.
bud the problem is that when I change the header, page should be reloaded if not, the Token would not be added to header.

Controller :

```
app.controller('catCtrl',['Api','$scope','$cookieStore','$rootScope',function (Api,$scope,$cookieStore,$rootScope) {
$scope.Login = function(){
    Api.loginEmail($scope.log_email, $scope.pass, 'chrome', 'windows','').success(function(response){
      $cookieStore.put('Auth-Key', 'Token ' + response.token);

      $scope.is_Loggedin = true;
      $scope.showLoginWin();
    }).error(function(response){
      $scope.log_email = null;
      $scope.pass = null;
      $scope.error = response.error;
    });
  };
}
```

App.run :

```
app.run(['$cookieStore','$http',function($cookieStore, $http){

  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $cookieStore.get('Auth-Key');
}]);
```

How can I change the header without reloading page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to add your token on further request after login.

You can try angular interceptor. Here is few Answers related how to add toke via interceptor.

[Interceptor Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944997/angularjs-http-custom-header-for-all-requests)

[Interceptor example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552892/angularjs-http-interceptor-resend-all-request-after-token-refresh)

sample Code:

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
  return {
    request: function (config) {    
      config.headers['Authorization'] = $cookieStore.get('Auth-Key');     

      return config;
    }
  };
});
```

In your service layer, Ignore verification this header for Login.